# How to deal with oversized page objects with Java and Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm writing a test suite using Webdriver, and I've found that using the page object pattern one of my classes is ending up with 1000+ LoC and around 40 methods. With C#, I'd just use regions and partial classes to break this down - however, with Java, neither of these options are available. What do you find the best way to create maintainable code with Webdriver for extremely complex pages?

Answer (score 1):

I am creating classes for the logical parts of the page, i.e. header, footer, comment section, etc and then the page have them as instance variables with getters. This is also very useful if some elements are common to multiple pages (header/footer usually are)

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory to represent all the properties of a page in a single page object. In our application our landing page has few tabs in it. Lets assume one is for price, then one for offer and another one for order. We have 4 page objects to represent this landing page.
One for the landing page itself and 3 more for the tabs within the landing page.

It is practically not possible to have one page object per page rule anymore, think about creating one for Gmail app :)